# Exclude unnecessary node modules from war

Tags: angular, npm, maven-3, package.json

I am creating a web application in which I using Maven, Spring, Hibernate, Angular. The size of war file if very large(151 MB) out of which 107 MB for node modules so please tell me how can I remove unnecessary node modules from war file to keep its size reasonable.
This is my npm dependencies :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mydatepicker": "^1.6.1",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^1.1.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4",
    "ng2-auto-complete": "^0.10.9"


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your directory structure is but in general it should work by adding something like this im your .pom:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <packagingExcludes>node_modules/**</packagingExcludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

(see [WAR Plugin Docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html))

Besides node_modules/** you might also exclude src/**. I'd check the .war file to see if there are other directories/files you can also exclude.

If your Angular app is packaged in a separate .jar that is included in the .war this looks slightly different, e.g.:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
            <targetPath>META-INF/resources</targetPath>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>node_modules/**</exclude>
                <exclude>src/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: But after that will I get js files required in my application that are part of node modules??

Comment: Sorry I have just assumed that you are using angular-cli, is this the case? If so, angular-cli will package all your code, assets and stuff into the "dist" folder and the bundled .js (vendor, polyfills, etc.) files will contain both, your code and the libraries code required from your application. Is this the case or are you using another packaging mechanism (webpack or so)?

Comment: I am using systemJS.